# Qt ожидание завершения работы потоков

Tags: qt, многопоточность, qt5

Есть класс. Важный момент: вся его работа завязана через его конструктор и конструкторы родительских классов, т.е. после завершения работы конструкторов - объект нам не нужен. Нужно поместить несколько объектов в отдельный поток, чтобы конструкторы отработали именно там, дождаться завершения конструкторов всех объектов и продолжить работу программы. У меня есть:
`main`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyThread* first = new MyThread;
    MyThread* second = new MyThread;
    QThread* fThread = new QThread;
    QThread* sThread = new QThread;

    first->moveToThread(fThread);
    second->moveToThread(sThread);

    fThread->start();
    sThread->start();

    /*Тут будем ожидать завершение работы всех конструкторов*/
    qDebug() << "Done!";

    return a.exec();
}
```

`MyThread`

```
class MyThread: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyThread(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~MyThread();
    void go();
protected:
    int now_count;
    int max_count;

};

MyThread::MyThread(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent){
    max_count = 100;
    go();
}

void MyThread::go(){
    now_count = 0;
    while(now_count<=max_count){
        qDebug() << QString::number(now_count);
        now_count++;
        QThread::sleep(0.1);
    }
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы объекты создавались в потоке? Как проверить, что все потоки в "простое" или еще что-то, что будет означать, что конструктор завершил работу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Для того, чтобы объекты создавались в потоке, их нужно создавать в этом потоке, т.е. примерно так:

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
    protected :
        void run()
        {
            // Создание объектов.
            // Работа с объектами.
        }
}
```

(Ясно, что конструктор класса `MyThread` может иметь параметры, необходимые для правильного создания объектов.)

2) Чтобы дождаться завершения работы потока, нужно использовать метод 
[`QThread::wait`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qthread.html#wait):

```
int main()
{
    // . . .

    MyThread* thread1 = new MyThread();
    MyThread* thread2 = new MyThread();

    thread1->wait();
    thread2->wait();

    // . . .

    delete thread1;
    delete thread2;

    // . . .
}
```

Если же надо просто **проверить**, работает поток или нет, то можно использовать тот же метод, передав ему ноль в качестве параметра:

```
if (thread1->wait(0)) {
    // Поток завершил работу.
}
else {
    // Поток всё ещё работает.
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.